# Dynamic Alocation in c not working

Tags: c, pointers, structure, allocation

I'm getting exit(1)(if there's some error in the allocation) every time i try to run the case 1. And i have no ideia why, can i get some help ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct hospede{             //guest
    int numreg;     //register num
    char nome[80];
    int acompanhante;   //n of ppl
    int dias;   //time to stay
    estado tabela;
}hospede;

typedef struct quarto{          //room
    int num;    //num do quarto
    char categoria;     //[S] ou [F]
    char status;        //[L] ou [O]
    estado stats;
    }quarto;

void alocaHospede(hospede **hosp, int tam);
void alocaQuartos(quarto **quar, int tam);
void geraQuartos(quarto *quar);
void checkIn(hospede *hosp, int tam);

int main()
{
    hospede *hpd = NULL;
    quarto *qrt = NULL;
    quarto quart;
    int qtd = 0;
    char op;
    int x;

    qrt = &quart;
    geraQuartos(qrt);
    do{
        printf("\n1-CheckIn\n>");
        scanf("%i", &x);
        fflush(stdin);
        switch(x){
        case 1:
            alocaHospede(&hpd, qtd+1);       
            checkIn(hpd, qtd);
        }
        printf("\nDeseja continuar? \n");
        scanf("%c", &op);
        fflush(stdin);
    }while(op!='n' && op!='N');

    return 0;
}
void checkIn(hospede *hosp, int tam){
    printf("\nwork\n");
}//checkIn
void alocaHospede(hospede **hosp, int tam){
    *hosp = (hospede*)realloc(*hosp, tam*sizeof(hospede));
    if(*hosp == NULL)
        exit(1);
}//aloca hospede

void alocaQuartos(quarto **quar, int tam){
if((*quar = (quarto *) realloc(*quar, tam * sizeof(quarto)))== NULL)
    exit(1);
}//alocaQuartos


void geraQuartos(quarto *quar){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<15;i++,quar++){
        (*quar).num = i+1;
    }
}//geraQuartos
```

OBS:

I Removed some structures and unions that aren't being used yet to make the code shorter, also i'll do the allocation to the rooms as well, i think it's the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop in `geraQuartos` is treating its argument as a pointer to an array of 15 `quartos` structures. But it's a pointer to just one structure, so it's writing outside the bounds of the object. This is causing undefined behavior, and in this case it's overwriting `hpd` so it's not `NULL`. This then causes `realloc` to fail because the first argument isn't `NULL` or a pointer that was previously returned by `malloc`.

Change the declaration of `quart` to:

```
quarto quart[15];
```

and then do:

```
geraQuartos(quart);
```

Answer (score 1):

geraQuartos(qrt) causes stack overflow since quart is only 1-entry-lengthed but you writes 1st ~ 15th entries inside the function.
Anything strange could happen on stack overflow.